# HTML / атрибут poster тега video Можно ли формат webP?

Tags: css3, html5, видео, теги, стандарт

При проверке страницы, элементом Chrome DevTools одна из рекомендаций использовать современные форматы графики - webP.
Если для обычных изображений есть тег picture в котором есть фоллбек для браузера Safary который данный формат не поддерживает, то как быть с постером к видео? Как правильнее, поставить webP или ужать изображение постера до максимальной компрессии ?